# Add objects in a NSMutableArray declared in another function

Tags: objective-c, c, variables, nsmutablearray

Ideally, I would like to make a function add objects in a NSMutableArray, and then do whatever I want with this array in another function.

Here is what I've tried to do lately, of course it doesn't work but it gives you an idea of what I want to do:

```
- (void)someThing 
{  
   (...)

NSMutableArray *arrayOfThings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

while (theObject = [aNSEnumerator nextObject]) {
   const char *theObject_fixed = [theObject UTF8String]; 

   function_something(theObject_fixed);
}

// do something with arrayOfThings


}



void function_something(const char *file)
{

    (...)


unsigned int *p = memmem(buffer, fileLen, bytes, 4);

NSMutableString *aString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:48];

unsigned long off_to_string = 0x10 + 4 + ((void *)p) - ((void *)buffer);

for (unsigned long c = off_to_string; c<off_to_string+0x30; c++)
{

[aString appendFormat:@"%.2x", (int)buffer[c]];

}

 NSLog(@"%s: %@", file, aString);   

[arrayOfThings addObject:[aString copy]];

 free(buffer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to go about this:

The first requires only a slight modification to your code will allow you to do what you want:
In the funciton *someThing* pass the mutable array as an additional parameter.

```
function_something(theObject_fixed, arrayOfThings);
```

Then change function_something to accept that parameter.

```
void function_something(const char *file, NSMutableArray *arrayOfThings) {
    // Code remains the same
}
```

The other and in my opinion better solution would be for the function_something to return the fixed string as an NSString object and let *someThing* do the adding to the mutable array.
So we get something like this in *someThing*:

```
...
NSString *aString = function_something(theObject_fixed);
[arrayOfThings addObject:aString];
```

And then a redefined *function_something*:

```
NSString* function_something(const char *file) {
    ...
    return [aString autorelease];
}
```

By the way, your code is leaking memory. Be careful with you retain/release/autorelease.

Comment: Thanks, I chose your second solution and it works perfectly ! By the way, could you explain me a bit why it's leaking ?

Comment: in the function function_something you are using alloc/init so the retain count is 1 on that string and it's never released.